# Structure packing with C macros

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to implement `#pragma pack` directive through `_Pragma оperator`, to create macros for data structure alignment.
All this is described in the book in the book *"C: In a Nutshell"*

```
#define  STR(s)  #s
#define  ALIGNMENT(n) _Pragma( STR (pack(n)) )
#define  ALIGNLEVEL(l) ALIGNMENT(l)
int  main()
{
   ....
    if(1)
    {
        ALIGNLEVEL(1)
        printf("%s\n", STR(Byte-aligned: no padding));>
    }
    else
    {
        ALIGNLEVEL(4)
        printf("%s\n", STR(four-byte: boundaries));

    }
    typedef struct s
    {
        size_t l_num;
        short  h_num;
        char ch;
    } s;
```

The result that I expect is size of my structure to be equal to **7 bytes** (byte-aligned) or **11 bytes** in x64-bit platform. 
Code above is compiled with *GCC 4.7.x* with `-Werror` option, and return result is **8 bytes** (32-bit OS).

What can be wrong with this macro?
Why is this happening?

Comment: I doubt the use of macros is relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is written under the assumption that pragmas are affected by the results of the evaluation of an `if` statement's test. This is not the case: the second pragma simply overrides the first one, and the structure packing alignment gets unconditionally set to 4. If you comment out the second `ALIGNLEVEL`, you will get the expected result (tested with gcc 4.8.1 on ia32 and x86-64).

It makes sense that the compiler ignores a run-time construct such as `if` when looking at inherently compile-time pragmas. Even though your `if` has a constant test, it could be easily changed to a non-constant, and the compiler would fail to provide consistent results. If you need different alignments in different situations, you will have to use the preprocessor:

```
#if SOME_CONDITION
    ALIGNLEVEL(1)
    printf("%s\n", STR(Byte-alligned: no padding));>
#else
    ALIGNLEVEL(4)
    printf("%s\n", STR(four-byte: boundaries));
#endif
```

If you need to use different alignments based on a *runtime* condition, you will have to define both structures and switch between the code that uses one or the other, based on a well-chosen abstraction.